# Moving data in excel rows multiple under single column

Tags: excel, vba

I am having some problems with moving multiple data rows under one column.

How it currently is

[image]

And this is how i would like it

[image]

I have tryed to find a solution to this problem for some time now, but i can't seem to find anything that does this.

Thank you in advance

Comment: You're second image doesn't appear to be working (for me anyway) Could you check the link?

Comment: seems to be working now at leaste, they are both showing ( thank you to the person adding them ) 
http://img854.imageshack.us/img854/6537/howiwouldlikeit.jpg is the direct link to the second image

Answer (score 1):

Paste Special, Transpose is the only thing that comes close to what you want, but that won't do it for you. I think you are going to have to write a macro or do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Was thinking of a way to do it with worksheet functions but came up blank. Using VBA is probably a lot simpler.

This is a fairly simple way to do it. It Looks at `Sheet1` and outputs to `Sheet2` (as it would overwrite some values if you tried to output to the same sheet without caching all the values first).

This works due to how the `Sheet.Cells` Object(?) stores data, which is `A1,B1..Y1,Z1,A2,B2..Y2,Z2`
where `Y` and `Z` last cells in the row. (the opposite of your result basically)

```
Sub Main()
Dim S1 As Worksheet
Dim S2 As Worksheet
Dim Cell As Variant
Dim Row As Long

    Set S1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") ' Source Sheet
    Set S2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2") ' Destination Sheet

    Row = 1 ' Start Output on this row

    For Each Cell In S1.UsedRange.Cells

        S2.Cells(Row, 1).Value = Cell.Value
        Row = Row + 1

    Next Cell

End Sub
```